# Component returning undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working with two files App.js which renders the components and a Search.js which holds a search bar component. The App.js looks like:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Greeting from '../Greeting/Greeting';
import InputWithLabel from '../Search/Search';
import List from '../List/List';

// App component
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <InputWithLabel
        id="search"
        value={searchTerm}
        isFocused
        onInputChange={handleSearch}
      >
        <strong>Search:</strong>
      </InputWithLabel>
      <hr />
      <List list={searchedStories} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The Search.js component looks like:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

// Search bar, destructure props search, onSearch
function InputWithLabel({ id, value, type = "text", onInputChange, isFocused, children, }) {
    const stories = [
        {
            title: 'React',
            url: 'https://reactjs.org/',
            author: 'Jordan Walke',
            num_comments: 3,
            points: 4,
            objectID: 0,
        },
        {
            title: 'Redux',
            url: 'https://redux.js.org/',
            author: 'Dan Abramov, Andrew Clark',
            num_comments: 2,
            points: 5,
            objectID: 1,
        },
    ];

    const useSemiPersistentState = (key, initialState) => {
        const [value, setValue] = React.useState(
            localStorage.getItem(key) || initialState
        );

        React.useEffect(() => {
            localStorage.setItem(key, value);
        }, [value, key]);

        return [value, setValue]
    };

    // Set state on searchTerm, setSearchTerm with custom hook
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useSemiPersistentState(
        'search',
        'React'
    );

    // Get the value of search input
    const handleSearch = (event) => {
        setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
    };

    // Check if user input matches stories array
    // toLowerCase() both values
    const searchedStories = stories.filter((story) => story.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
    );

    const inputRef = React.useRef();

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (isFocused && inputRef.current) {
            inputRef.current.focus();
        }
    }, [isFocused]);

    return (
        <>
            <label htmlFor={id}>{children}</label>
            &nbsp;
            <input
                ref={inputRef}
                id={id}
                type={type}
                value={value}
                autoFocus={isFocused}
                onChange={onInputChange}
            />
        </>
    )
}

export default InputWithLabel;
```

The errors i receive are:
****Failed to compile****
src/Components/App/App.js
Line 62:16: 'searchTerm' is not defined no-undef
Line 64:24: 'handleSearch' is not defined no-undef
Line 69:19: 'searchedStories' is not defined no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

I must be passing {searchTerm}, {handleSearch}, {searchedStories} in wrong but dont know how its wrong?

Comment: You App component doesnt pass in `searchTerm` in its props

Answer (score 0):

`onChange={onInputChange}` should be `onChange={handleSearch}`
and you can remove the props to your component

```
  <InputWithLabel
        id="search"        
        isFocused   
      >
```

since you're not using them.
Your `app` componetn should be responsible for holding the

```
 const stories = [
```

array, then you'll be able to use `searchedStories` in App.

But I suggest you read the React docs a bit closer.